# Selenium replace value for the input field with sendKeys() method

Tags: java, selenium

I have an unexpected issue with the `sendKeys()` method:

A long time before it all worked fine, but unexpectedly the (certain(!)) values are replaced when the code tries to set data into the input field:

[image]

For example, if I set value `USER_NAME` into the field, value replaced with `/tmp/7d7b7...../upload123...file/USER_NAME`. As we can see - some path was added into the `USER_NAME` value.

I added logs to the method and we can see a moment when the value was replaced:

```java
    clearInputFld(inputFld);
    Log.info("INSIDE clearAndTypeIntoInputField() ---------> value after clearing: " + inputElement.getAttribute("value"));
    Log.info("INSIDE clearAndTypeIntoInputField() ---------> value to set: " + value);

    inputElement.sendKeys(value);

    Log.info("INSIDE clearAndTypeIntoInputField() ---------> value after set: " + inputElement.getAttribute("value"));
```

Output:

```
INSIDE clearAndTypeIntoInputField() ---------> value after clearing: 
INSIDE clearAndTypeIntoInputField() ---------> value to set: USER_NAME
INSIDE clearAndTypeIntoInputField() ---------> value after set: /tmp/7d7b7...../upload123...file/USER_NAME
```

So we can be sure - value sets exactly at the moment when value sets into the field.

**Important to know, and conclusions:**

- Not all users replaced - Only several certain users! So I suppose a part of users is cached. But I do not understand the process with which this happens, why this happens, and where these users might be cached.
- I also restarted the docker, so it seems the problem is not in the automatic side.
- **Is it possible that this issue occurs via the backend or UI part?**

Comment: sendKeys or sendCase?

Comment: Privet, try using clear() before you input data. Or you are already using it?

Comment: where do you set 'value' variable value

Comment: Check the way you get your USER_NAME, if you getting it by: `System.getProperty("user.name");` or similar that may cause the issue

Comment: I guess the problem is not with `sendKeys()` method rather than with the data the method receives from somewhere and just passes to the web element. So I'd suggest you debugging the process passing the `value` here.

Comment: include the HTML of the form in your post.  This sort of sounds like it's dealing with an input field of type file.  There is a special feature for remote file uploads.  (are you using remote driver or local?)

Comment: @vitaliis dobrogo dnia, Already using

Comment: @Eliyahu you can see logs - the value is correct

Comment: You taking the logs inside the web element while I mentioned tracking the value passed to the sendKeys() method from where it is coming.

Comment: @Prophet this value doesn't change anywhere before this method.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there is a script running on the page that changes the input you type, as this is a password field.

What I suggest is that you use the Robot object to mimic keyboard strokes.
First click on the text field using Selenium, then launch the Robot code (use package Java.awt):

```
Robot robot = null;
    try {
        robot = new Robot();            
        for (char c : textToType.toCharArray()) {
            int keyCode = KeyEvent.getExtendedKeyCodeForChar(c);
            if (KeyEvent.CHAR_UNDEFINED == keyCode) {
                logger.error("Key code not found for character '" + c + "'");
            } else {
                try {
                    robot.keyPress(keyCode);
                    robot.delay(10);
                    robot.keyRelease(keyCode);
                    robot.delay(10);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    if (c == '_') {
                        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
                        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_MINUS);
                        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_MINUS);
                        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
                    }
                    if (c == ':') {
                        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
                        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SEMICOLON);
                        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SEMICOLON);
                        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);           
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        logger.error(ex.getMessage());
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

According to Logs, I think there is something come with the value.

Suggest trying :
Get the changed text, do some operation, fill it back

```
string[] temp;
temp = (inputElement.Text).Split('/');
inputElement.Sendkeys(temp(temp.Length - 1));
```

Comment: My apologies @fubao, it appears I may have misread your answer. It looked to me like you were requesting clarification (as in: could you try this and tell me what happens), but on re-read it appears that is not the case.

Comment: You just offered me to set the same value in the input field...again. This is doesn't have a sense.